# Setting limit of line renderer distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a line renderer that has a free line that goes to long distances when a raycast is casted. However I want to limit the distance to lets say x,y,z = 5 no matter how long the line should be depending on the raycast. How do I use Mathf.Clamp() function in this script for my line renderer to limit a distance of 5.
So that I can hide the line after it has crossed the distance limit by keeping the raycast activated? So that only 1/4th of the line is visible but it still collides with a collider?

```
private LineRenderer _lineRenderer;

    [Tooltip("Maximum range for aiming.")]
    public float Range = 100;

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the set of points that represent the aiming line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="points"></param>

    public override void GetPoints(List<Vector3> points)
    {
        Ray aimRay;
        LocomotionTeleport.InputHandler.GetAimData(out aimRay);
        points.Add(aimRay.origin);
        points.Add(aimRay.origin + aimRay.direction * Range);
    }

private void UpdateAim(Data obj)
    {
        _lineRenderer.sharedMaterial.color = obj.TargetValid ? new Color32(107, 202, 23, 255) : new Color32(202, 61, 23, 255);

        var points = obj.Points;
        
        _lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Count;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            _lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, points[i]); //Limit distance of line 
            float _Distance = Vector3.Distance(points[0],points[1]);
            Debug.Log(""+_Distance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any raycast in your code, where do you get the points from? For a straight line wouldn't two points start + end be enough? Also note that [`SetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html) in one single go is way better than looping and using `SetPosition`

Comment: @derHugo it is a little complicated. I am using the teleportation library from Oculus, the code is from there. So basically there are two SetPosition (0 and 1) and the vectors (points[i]) are assigned from the raycast with the hand. I want to hide half the line so I thought if I could limit the distance, it should work.

Comment: So if you already now that there are only two points then what is the loop for? ^^

Comment: @derHugo just did not want to mess up the Oculus code :p

Comment: Well now that you added it .... does the `Range` actually change how the raycast works? Because otherwise you simply would set the range to 5 right? ^^

Comment: No it does not matter :) Only the line distance is limited but the Physics.Raycast goes long distances. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you already know you get always exactly two points as feedback:

- `points[0]` origin of the raycast
- `points[1]` end/hitpoint of the ray.

In order to limit this to a certain distance simply do

```
public float maxDisplayLength = 5f;

public Color validColor = new Color32(107, 202, 23, 255);
public Color invalidColor = new Color32(202, 61, 23, 255);

// would be enough to do this only once
private void Start()
{
    _lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
}

private void UpdateAim(Data obj)
{
    _lineRenderer.sharedMaterial.color = obj.TargetValid ?  validColor: invalidColor;

    var points = obj.Points;

    if(vector.magnitude > maxDisplayLength)
    {
        var direction = (points[1] - points[0]).normalized;

        // Fix the second/end point to a position in the same direction 
        // as originally but maxLength distance from origin
        points[1] = points[0] + direction * maxDisplayLength;
   }

    _lineRenderer.SetPositions(points);
}
```

As said [`SetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html) in one go is more efficient then assigning them one by one.

---

**ACTUALLY**

Now that you added the rest of the code it seems that the

```
public float Range = 100;
```

anyay does not change how the raycast works and is only used for the LineRenderer.

... so it should be enough to only set the `Range` to your target max length since the same calculation as I suggested is already done in

```
points.Add(aimRay.origin);
points.Add(aimRay.origin + aimRay.direction * Range);
```

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out something. I will also post as an alternate answer.

Comment: UPDATE: Ah great I can set only the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only two points for a line renderer (points[0] and points[1]), one does not need a loop to begin with. The user can use Mathf.Clamp() function after calculating the distance between the two points. The user `derHugo`'s code is more structured. This is only an alternate answer.

```
    private void UpdateAimData(LocomotionTeleport.AimData obj)
    {
        _lineRenderer.sharedMaterial.color = obj.TargetValid ? new Color32(107, 202, 23, 255) : new Color32(202, 61, 23, 255);

        var points = obj.Points;
        //        Debug.Log("AimVisualLaser: count: " + points.Count);
        _lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Count;
        //_lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(points.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++) //Not required
        {
            _lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, points[i]);

            Vector3 dir = points[1] - points[0];
            float dist = Mathf.Clamp(Vector3.Distance(points[0], points[1]), 0, DistanceLimit_Float);
            points[1] = points[0] + (dir.normalized * dist);

            Debug.Log(""+dist);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isLineStarted)
        {
            if (line.positionCount > MaxCapacity)
            {
                Vector3[] linePositions = new Vector3[line.positionCount];
                List<Vector3> newPos = new List<Vector3>();
                line.GetPositions(linePositions);
                newPos = linePositions.ToList();
                newPos.RemoveAt(0);
                linePositions = newPos.ToArray();
                line.SetPositions(linePositions);
            }
            
            Vector3 currentPos = GetWorldCoordinate(Input.mousePosition);
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, line.GetPosition(line.positionCount - 1));
            if (distance > minimumVertexDistance)
            {
                UpdateLine();
            }
        }
```